# Configuring Search with a load balanced CMS

Tags: 2011, search

We have Tridion 2011 and are experiencing issues with Search.

We have 2 Content Manager servers behind a network load balancer.

Does search need to be configured differently in this scenario?

I've looked in the documentation and can't find a guide for this, does anyone know if it exists?

### Update

The issue is that not all items appear in search results, for example a search for recently changed items does not show all items that have recently changed. We thought this was a configuration issue, which the answer below confirms.

Comment: You haven't explained the issues you are experiencing with the Search. Updating your question with the details will help you to get more relevant responses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, Yes. You could scale the CMS Search Instances. Check the documentation
http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_E7DB2BEDD94C43359C6511D3C69010C0 (requires login).

This was answered in our old forums. https://forum.sdltridion.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=7460
(copying here for convenience).

1. Decide on Search Host Master out of your 4 servers. let's say : server 1
2. You need to edit the TcmSearchHost.exe.config and add the config to make this master. (follow the sdl doc instructions for master)
3. Go to Server 2 and now make this as slave. edit the TcmSearchHost.exe.config to make this slave (again follow sdl doc instructions for slave)
4. Repeat Step # 3 on server 3 and 4.
5. Now.. On All servers , Open the Tridion MMC and update the Indexer Service Settings to point to server1:8983
   This step will make all CMS Servers talk to server 1 for indexing content.

You need to restart all the necessary services to apply the config..

Please be aware that if the server1 goes down your indexing is down.. but not the Search Query.